# MySQL query returning None and then ignoring if statement

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

The variables `logged_in_before` and `already_set_date` are `Null` in the database but the if statement still executes and prints "date already set" when it shouldn't be. I've tried so many combinations using is None, == None, == "None", == "Null" etc but it's not working.

The values are stored as VARCHAR(255) in the database and are returning a tuple of (None,) when I print them out.

What am I missing, I assume it's something to do with the values being strings rather than objects set to None?

```
    def login(email, password):
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", database="")
        cur = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = %s and password = %s", (email, password))
        result = cur.fetchone()
        mydb.commit()
        if result:
            cur.execute("SELECT logged_in_before FROM users WHERE email = %s", (email,))
            logged_in_before = cur.fetchone()
            mydb.commit()
            if logged_in_before:
                cur.execute("SELECT date_of_visit FROM users WHERE email = %s", (email,))
                already_set_date = cur.fetchone()
                mydb.commit()
                if already_set_date:
                    print("date already set")
                else:
                    print("date not set")
            else:
                cur.execute("UPDATE users SET logged_in_before = 'yes' WHERE email = %s",
                            (email,))
                mydb.commit()
                print("Now logged in")
        else:
            invalid_login()

        cur.close()
        mydb.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with NULL values, you would use IS NULL instead of = NULL. You can also use IS NOT NULL.

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure what you meant at first but reading up around it looks like I do the following and put it after the ```WHERE``` statement ```cur.execute("SELECT logged_in_before FROM users WHERE email = %s AND logged_in_before IS NOT NULL", (email,))``` Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to help :)